# Highchart legend covers chart content

Tags: highcharts, legend-properties

Now I'm working on `Highchart`. I put legends at the bottom of the chart.
As number of series increases, legends goes up covering the chart content so that it's hard to see the chart.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome on SO, please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a question and then we will be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide your code (live demo on jsfiddle ideally).